# need for loop with conditional continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I need to "continue" based on a checkbox.

HTML:

```
<input type = "text" id = "E1" /><input type="checkbox" id="C1">
<input type = "text" id = "E2" /><input type="checkbox" id="C2">
<input type = "text" id = "E3" /><input type="checkbox" id="C3">
<input type = "text" id = "E4" /><input type="checkbox" id="C4">
```

JS:

```
for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) { 
if ("$C" +i.checked == true) {continue;} 
...;  
}

</script>
```

Comment: you mean start from zero again if checkbox is  checked ?

Comment: No. Just not finish that iteration. But continue with the next item.

Comment: What is the specific problem or error you are having?

Comment: you can't access your object just by putting a $ before their id

Comment: Most important: what are you trying to achieve? And where do you want to print that output?

Comment: @verlager what is your expected result ?

Comment: My hoped for result is that the loop will skip one iteration if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I take any answer in js or jquery.

Comment: `"$C" +i.checked` isn't even valid. You need to use `getElementById` or `querySelector`.

Comment: @verlager - you don't need a loop, you need an event handler. Any click of the checkbox will invoke the printing of the continue button

Comment: OK I will try that.

Comment: @staypuftman Where did you get the idea that he wants to print a continue button?

Comment: I have 48 of these checkboxes. The ones I select are the ones to be ignored in the for loop.

Comment: Why does your loop start at `0` when the IDs start at `C1`?

Comment: I fixed that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` is the correct keyword to use to achieve this. I suspect that the issue in your case is that the `if` statement is never true.

I think you want this:

```
// Add 1 to index first and then concatenate with "#C" to create jQuery id selector
if ($('#C' + (i + 1)).is(':checked')) { continue; }
```

Your `if` statement above is functionally equivalent (when checked) to:

```
if ("$Ctrue" == true) { continue; }
```

*$C* and the string value of the Boolean are concatenated.

Comment: If there is additional relevant info, please add it to you original post, or comment here.

Comment: That adds too much complexity... isn't there a **simple** solution to this? I'm willing to tab over the input fields. I wrote this post just because it is simple. If add the real code, *no one will answer*.

Comment: I haven't added any complexity, I've simply corrected your erroneous code. Your if statement will never be true.

Comment: Success!! Thank you, Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

`$("#C" + i).prop('checked')` gives you `true` if the i-th checkbox is checked.

**NOTE:**

- The way you loop is not good as you always need to adjust your conditions if you add/remove inputs.
- Also your for-loop condition was off as you begin at `1`

```js
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++) { 
  if ($("#C" + i).prop('checked'))
    continue;

  console.log(i + ' unchecked');
  // do some stuff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type = "text" id = "E1" /><input type="checkbox" id="C1" checked>
<input type = "text" id = "E2" /><input type="checkbox" id="C2">
<input type = "text" id = "E3" /><input type="checkbox" id="C3">
<input type = "text" id = "E4" /><input type="checkbox" id="C4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(){
for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) { 
if($("#C"+i).is(':checked'))
continue;
console.log($("#E"+i).val())

}

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "text" id = "E1" /><input type="checkbox" id="C1">
<input type = "text" id = "E2" /><input type="checkbox" id="C2">
<input type = "text" id = "E3" /><input type="checkbox" id="C3">
<input type = "text" id = "E4" /><input type="checkbox" id="C4">

<button id="test" >Test</button>
```

In this case, it won't be logging the values for those inputs who don't have adjacent checkbox checked for example

Comment: With this method I need 48 identical ID's of "test". That won't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is break up your logic so that your program is readable and you can express it in the higher-level terms

```
function getCheckboxes() {
  const checkboxes = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <5; ++i) {
    checkboxes.push(document.getElementById(`E${i}`);
  }
  return checkboxes;
}

getCheckboxes()
  .filter(checkbox => !checkbox.checked)
  .forEach(checkbox => {
    // do something with an unchecked checkbook
  });
```

Answer (score -3):

Your loop never gets run because there are no event listeners in your code. You need to have an event listener tied to your checkbox inputs. It would look like this:

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[name=checkbox]");

checkbox.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
  if(this.checked) {
    // output button here
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't work. I have 48 of these checkboxes. Have to use an ID, not a name, sir.

Comment: His question doesn't even mention outputting a button, but it specifically says he wants to loop through the items and skip the ones that are checked.